# Prefetcher max cache size reached

Tags: android, caching, logcat

After working a while with my Mediaplayer streamer project I got the Logcat saying: "Max cache size reached" every second. Is it normal? And should I do something about it? It plauges me and I have to restart my emulator to get rid of it.

```
08-17 17:34:28.772: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:29.772: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:30.772: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:31.772: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:32.775: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:33.778: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
08-17 17:34:34.779: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max cache size reached
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling sd cache partion on the emulator.

It's done by Creating a new AVD (Android Virtual Device) and then in the Hardware box adding "Cache partition support".