# Facing problem in Android Video streaming

Tags: android, video, streaming

I created a simple application which will stream video from an URL, it works fine when i point to some local URL like,

```
http://192.168.X.XX:XXX/Tutorial/TestVideo.mp4
```

But when try to point some external URL like,

```
http://122.183.X.XX/Tutorial/TestVideo.mp4
```

the app is not working. In both the URLs i am having the same video file. When i work with the external URL i am getting the following logcat info

```
08-17 17:34:28.772: INFO/Prefetcher(34): max duration reached, size = 960201 bytes
```

Please find my code below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    preview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    preview.setEnabled(true);
    preview.bringToFront();
    MediaController mc=new MediaController(playerActivity.this);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(player_interface);
    mc.show(50);
    preview.setMediaController(mc );
    holder=preview.getHolder();

    holder.setFixedSize(400, 400);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd_play);
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {       
            mp.setDisplay(holder);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);               
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(playerActivity.this);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(playerActivity.this);
            mp.prepare();           
            mp.start();
            mp.seekTo(20000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem, please some body help me if you know the solution for this.

Thanks and Regards,

Rajapandian

Answer (score 0):

If this is occurring on the emulator try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505276/prefetcher-max-cache-size-reached/3532241#3532241) and try it on an actual phone. If this isn't the problem, you'll need to post the code you are using to load the video.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as you said i updated my code in the post.

Comment: Comment out mp.seekTo(20000) and see if you still have the problem. I haven't had this specific problem, but I have had issues with seeking to an unbuffered position.